# Angular 5 - unsafe:data:image/octet-stream

Tags: json, angular, image

I have data represented in [json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp); my problem is that I cannot read images starting with `data:image/octet-stream`.

During execution, the console print's an error that the string is unsafe. The error is as follows:

```
unsafe:data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBMQExAAD/7S6...
```

I have tried a few examples, but they do not work; they return a string of the images. Below is the json data I am reading:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Albany",
            "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
            "price": 15.49,
            "category": "Food",
            "type": "Breads",
            "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..."
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Blue Ribbon",
            "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
            "price": 13.99,
            "category": "Food",
            "type": "Breads",
            "image": "data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."
        },
        ...
    ]
```

I have a class in which I was trying to implement a hack to this problem:

```
export class MilkCreamComponent implements OnInit {

  allProducts: Array<Product> = [];
  quantity: number = 1;
  resultArray:any;
  milkProducts =[]

  constructor( private prod: ProductService, public _DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.allProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product-data') );
    //console.log( JSON.stringify( this.allProducts ) );

    var productMilk = this.allProducts.filter(item => item.type === 'Milk');
    this.milkProducts = productMilk;

    console.log( productMilk );
  }
}

interface Product {

  id: number;
  name: string;
  manufacture: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  type: string;
  image: string;
}
```

And my html is as follows:

```
<tr *ngFor="let prod of milkProducts">
    <td><img src={{prod.image}}   width="120" height="130"/></td>
    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
    <td>{{prod.manufacture}}</td>
    <td>R {{prod.price}}</td>

    <td><button class="btn btn-primary">data boy</button></td>
</tr>
```

I do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

your image url in the json are base64 format first you have to convert the base64 to normal image source then only you can show  the image on HTML template..

Comment: How will I do that?